# Missing the ability to link different artboards in an external document in Illustrator CC 2017

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, artboard, smartobject

Before I update my current Illustrator Version to CC 2017, I used to get a pop-up before placing external .ai files in my current document offering me multiple options as well as the ability to choose between all artboards from the external document.

Now when I try to place (CMD + Shift + P) an external .ai file in my document, it automatically places the first artboard. Also looked for some options in my "links" panel, but it seems the like the feature is gone.

I already searched the web for an answer but wasn't successful. So does anyone know if this feature was removed? Do I have to rely on my CC libraries instead? Or is there any other workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check `Show Import Options` when choosing a file to place.....